# Forth - convert ASCII code to char

Tags: forth

I try to write a program in Tachyon Forth for the Parallax Propeller microcontroller that reads data from the serial port.

The SERIN word returns the data as a number:

DECIMAL  ok
57600 SERBAUD  ok
31 SERIN . 36 ok

The "31 SERIN" reads data from pin P31 (RX). I typed "$" and got back 36.
How can I convert this number (ASCII code) into a string with a single char?
In this case with a single "$" sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with the string.  Here's one way to get a temporary string:

```
: char-to-string ( c -- a u ) pad c!  pad 1 ;
```

So e.g.

```
36 char-to-string type
$ ok
```